# Access the attribute of a variable in Twig

Tags: javascript, twig

I am using a twig variable in a javascript file. My goal is to access the attribute of the variable with a predifined string. Basically, I want to do this:

```
var a = 'data-foo';
console.log( {{ attribute(foo, a) }} );
```

Unfortunately, this is not working but if I directly use `console.log( {{ attribute(foo, 'data-foo') }} );`, It works, I do get my data.

For special purposes, I need to apply the first idea. I've tried different things like:

```
console.log("{{attribute(foo, "+a+")}}");
console.log( {{foo[a]}} );
console.log( {{ "foo."+a }} );
```

but none of this is working, javascript can't find the result and I get a blank answer from the console.

Comment: Twig is php, you can't pass javascript to php.

Comment: Twig is rendered serverside. You will need to fetch the data with ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to pass a JavaScript variable into a Twig function. This isn't directly possible.

```
{% set a = 'data-foo' %}
var a = '{{ a }}';
console.log( {{ attribute(foo, a) }} );
```

Here you will have the variable `a` available in both Twig and JavaScript.